# Create Razor Page Response Caching

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I've been trying to follow this guide
https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/custom-response-caching-in-asp.net-core-with-cache-invalidation
with the aim to create a caching layer which intercepts the OnGet methods and returns the response from a cache.

My aim is to return a response should the URL in question exist in the cache and prevent any view logic running and cut down on all render time.  Is this possible in Razor Pages?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried built in caching: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0?

Comment: I have yeah but I can't see how you would set a different TTL for server caching vs browser caching and how would you clear the cache should something urgent need changing like a price.  Thanks